# Uniqueness, show $x(t) > t^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following initial value problem $x'=x-t^{2} +2t$ where $x(0)=1$. Prove $x(t)>t^{2}$ for all t for which x is defined. The way to show this is to somehow use uniqueness to show this is true. We notice $f(t,x) = x-t^{2} +2t$ is defined for all t and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1$ is continuous over the entire region containing $(1,0)$. So uniqueness is satisfied but how can we use this to show $x(t)>t^{2}$ if our region can be considered to be the entire tx-plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might rewrite the equation as
$$(x - t^2)' = x - t^2$$
Let $y(t) = x(t) - t^2$, and $y(0) = 1 > 0$, so the equation has a solution
$y(t) = e^t$. Or $x(t) = e^t + t^2$. Since the original equation has a unique solution, this solution is indeed the solution for $ t > 0$. Clearly, $x(t) > t^2$.